# Is there a way to reduce the verbosity of using String.Format(...., p1, p2, p3)?

Tags: c#, string.format, verbosity

I often use `String.Format()` because it makes the building of strings more readable and manageable.

**Is there anyway to reduce its syntactical verbosity, e.g. with an extension method, etc.?**

```
Logger.LogEntry(String.Format("text '{0}' registered", pair.IdCode));

public static void LogEntry(string message)
{
    ...
}
```

e.g. I would like to use all my and other methods that receive a string the way I use `Console.Write()`, e.g.:

```
Logger.LogEntry("text '{0}' registered", pair.IdCode);
```

Comment: What I really want support for Miguel's patch: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Dec-20.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
static void LogEntry(string format, params object[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(format, args); // For example.
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
Logger.LogEntry("text '{0}' registered", pair.IdCode);
```

Comment: @Konrad param gives me a compiler error.  The keyword is params.

Answer (score 4):

If you control the `Logger.LogEntry` method, you can simply add an overload that encompasses the string.format.  Just declare the second parameter as a paramarray and you are good to go!

Comment: @Mitchel: I think that's a reasonable answer in this case, but I'd suggest that an extension on String is more generally useful.

Comment: @Steven - Yes and no, for his project yes, for other callers of Logger.LogEntry() an overload would be better

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make an extension method named FormatWith, which lets you say things like:

```
Logger.LogEntry("I hate my {0}".FormatWith(itemName));
```

It should be easy enough to roll your own, but here's an example: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/27/formatwith-string-format-extension-method.aspx

Comment: Great point, but from a developer perspective, Logger.LogEntry is a utility function that many people are going to call, it would be good, in my opinion to get the method to support it as well.  Plus that is just about as verbose as string.format.....  But to the authors point it is the most correct answer.

Comment: I don't disagree regarding the usefulness of the overload you suggested: I've done much the same myself.  I do disagree with the idea that a FormatWith method is as verbose as String.Format, not only because it's shorter but because having it (appear) as a non-static method makes it much less obtrusive.  I believe the real question is whether an ad hoc overload is a general solution.  You're not going to make an overload for every method that takes a string, but with an extension method, you get the benefit of doing so.

Comment: @Mitchel Sellers: Sorry, forgot to use an @you to make sure you saw the response.

Answer (score 1):

If `Logger.LogEntry` is a static method outside of your control, then no; you can only add extension methods to instances. If it is your type, you could add:

```
public static void LogEntry(string format, params object[] args) {
    ... string.Format(format,args) ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the params keyword to combine all of the arguments after the first argument into an array and pass that array to String.Format.

```
static void FormatString(string myString, params string[] format)
{
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format(myString, format));
}
```